# JSON root elements and encoding

Tags: javascript, java, json

I'm having a JSON deserialized from Java as follow:

**Java**

```
jsonInString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(graphDTO);
```

**JSON**

```
  "accounts" : [ {
    "name" : "1009427721",
    "value" : 16850.79,
    "children" : [ {
      "name" : "BITCOIN EARNINGS",
      "value" : 10734.24,
      "children" : [ {
        "name" : "2017",
        "value" : 1037.82,
        "children" : [ {
          "name" : "07",
          "value" : 518.91
        } ]
      } ]
    },  ...
```

The deserialized Java POJO being:

```
public class GraphDTO {

    private Set<Account> accounts = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<Account> getAccounts() {
        return accounts;
    }
}
```

**Questions**

1. How can I remove "accounts" from the generated JSON (first line) ?
2. Injecting the JSON form into JavaScript, I'm getting an encoded form like:
   `var data =  { &#034;accounts&#034; : [ {` ...
   How can I avoid this ?

Comment: How are you parsing JSON in javascript? Can you provide any code?

Comment: Yes: `<script> var data =  <c:out value="${graphDTOJSON}"/>; ... </script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to avoid the `accounts`, but you can do this:

```
jsonInString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(graphDTO.getAccounts());
```

We're waiting your way to parse JSON in javascript...

Comment: Thanks, your approach is giving me the structure I was looking for :) For the use in JavaScript, I do: `<script> var data = <c:out value="${graphDTOJSON}"/>; ... </script>` to be consume by a sunburst char(https://docs.anychart.com/Basic_Charts/Sunburst_Chart)

Comment: Why don't you use `JSON.parse(graphDTOJSON)` instead?

Comment: Parse will return an Object. Tried your approach with JSON.stringify, don't work. but passing now `var data = ${graphDTOJSON};` work.

Answer (score 0):

Got it work as follow:

1. Applying the answer of Mohicane:

   `mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(graphDTO.getAccounts())`
2. Injecting the JSON from Java to JavaScript (in a JSP) with:

   `var data = ${graphDTOJSON};`

Many thanks!

Comment: Is it possible you flag my answer as the right one if you think it's good?